# Google Maps is showing an empty blue screen

Tags: php, html, google-maps, css

I implemented Google Maps [here](http://strutmymutt.com/development/rescues/14350/info) with longitude & latitude coordinates. These are not showing though, only an empty blue screen is returned.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that `mapLat = document.getElementById('mapLat').value` has a value of `$aAddress.cf_location_latitude.value` as opposed to an actual latitude.

My guess is that this is a server side variable who's value should be rendered in the HTML